# Back button from activity is removing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I am trying to retain the state of `Fragment`. I have `MotherActivity` in which I have `FragmentOne`,`FragmentTwo`,`FragmentThree` and inside from `FragmentTwo` I am calling another activity `ChildActivity`. Problem is that When I am pressing back button in `ChildActivity` it is refreshing `MotherActivity` and not keeping the state of my `FragmentTwo` instead it is showing me `FragmentOne` which come first time.

I only want when I am pressing `BackButton` from `ChildActivity`, on container `FragmentTwo` should be there:

MainAcitivity:

```
public class MotherActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item1);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item2);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item3);

        bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    selectedFragment = FragmentOne.newInstance(bottomNavigation);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    selectedFragment = FragmentTwo.newInstance(bottomNavigation);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    selectedFragment = FragmentThree.newInstance(bottomNavigation);
                } 

                android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,selectedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


                return true;

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, FragmentOne.newInstance(bottomNavigation));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    public void setNotification(){
        bottomNavigation.setNotification("1", 1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //No call for super().
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(113, intent);
        finish();
        return;

    }
}
```

`FragmentTwo` from where I am calling `childActivity`:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    public static AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation1;
    Card_detail_Adapter_Footer searchabledapter;
    public static boolean showAddress = false;
    Fragment selectedFragment;

    public static FragmentTwo newInstance(AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation) {
        FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        bottomNavigation1 = bottomNavigation;
        showNotificationCounter(3);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view   = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        if(showAddress == true){
            showAddress = false;

      // From here I am calling ChildActivity

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChildActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

In `ChildActivity` simply calling `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Placing `onStart()` content of `MotherActivity` into `onCreate()` might resolve it. Place it within `onCreate()`  `android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, FragmentOne.newInstance(bottomNavigation));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: add the below code in your manifest mother activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `onStart()` method of your `MotherActivity.java` because when you open another activity from `FragmentTwo`, your MotherActivity `onStop()` gets called. When you press back button from `ChildActivity` `onStart()` of `MotherActivity` called which is replacing `FragmentTwo` from `FragmentOne` by committing transaction.
Please have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Put code from `onStart()` method into `onCreate()` method and check if configuration been changed:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, FragmentOne.newInstance(bottomNavigation));
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```